# Game won't open?

Tags: depth

I just purchased depth, and when I click start, the game says running for about a second, then it stops and doesn't open the game. I couldn't find a solution. I restarted steam, reinstalled the game. Any solution for this?

Comment: Is this the only game that does this?

Comment: @Ash Yes it's the only one

Comment: What components are in your computer? It's possible you don't reach the minimum specs.

Comment: @Nzall I have a 960 GTX, i7 processor, my specs work

Comment: If you go to task manager is something from the game or steam hung up somewhere in processes?

Comment: @n_palum Nothing unusual in task manager, the game doesn't appear